# Automation using xdotool and Xvfb

Tags: automation, x11

I'm trying to automate getting CPU sampler data from visualvm on production system. But to do this I need a way to automate tasks inside Xvfb.

I found that xdotool is good for such automation.
Right now I have following script:

```
Xvfb $DISPLAY -pixdepths 32 -screen 0 1280x1024x24 >/dev/null 2>&1 & XPID=$!

echo "Before twm"
#twm -display $DISPLAY &
gnome-wm &

#$VISUALVM --openpid $PID_TO_OPEN &

echo "Before gimp"
gimp &

sleep 5
xdotool search "GNU.*" windowactivate windowfocus key alt+f n

sleep 3
DISPLAY=:0.0
xwd -display :9.0 -root | xwdtopnm | pnmtopng > out.png

qiv out.png
```

It should open Xvfb, run gimp, and click File->New. It does that when I do it in normal X, but when I execute this script in Xvfb it looks like it doesn't pass keyboard events.
I tested it with mouse and it's the same, xdotool doesn't pass (or Xvfb doesn't accept) events from mouse.

Has anyone encoundered this problem and know a solution?

Comment: I have the same issue. I hope someone knows the answer...

Comment: For me using `xdotool type` instead of `xdotool key` worked. As an alternative you could try `xvkbd`.

Comment: ["If you are trying to send key input to a specific window, and it does not appear to be working, then it's likely your application is ignoring the events xdotool is generating. This is fairly common."](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool.xhtml#sendevent_notes)

Comment: Command to run `gimp` into a X display and connect via VNC: `sudo x11vnc -storepasswd 1234 /tmp/vncpass && xvfb-run --listen-tcp --server-num 30 --auth-file /tmp/xvfb.auth -s "-ac -screen 0 1920x1080x24" gimp & x11vnc -rfbport 4544 -rfbauth /tmp/vncpass -display :30 -forever -auth /tmp/xvfb.auth & vncviewer -passwd /tmp/vncpass $(hostname):4544`